# Grid View not accepting my databind due to retrieved column names, or maybe an error on my part

Tags: sql, vb.net, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to figure out exactly why my Grid View is not accepting my databind. The first problem I ran into was that it needed to be dynamically created, and had to rework my logic/structure to what it is now.

I believe the issue to lie with the actual result set that gets passed from the initial SQL query in PestList back BindGridView shown below. I have been trying out a couple of things like reworking selects, multiple SQL queries etc. I have also tried to incorporate and CAST the columns to Strings with CAST(value as Varchar) etc.

My next idea was to try to add a method to build the SQL string in sections, but I'm not sure if I am even going about this the right way anymore.

This is the method that uses the initial set sql select I built in FlameRobin (table is full of test data and method names have been altered slightly):

```
Private Sub getPestList()

    tempVal = "With tmp1(Field) As " +
    " (select distinct t2.ORCHARDDETAILID from PESTMONITOR t2), " +
    " tmp2(MyPivot) As " +
    " (select 'iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = ' || Field || ', t2.QUANTITY, 0) as ' || MyField || ' ' from tmp1) " +
    " Select 'select t2.MONITORDATE, '||list(distinct MyPivot)||' from PESTMONITOR t2 order by 1' from PESTMONITOR cross join tmp2"

    Using execSQL As New FbCommand((tempVal), con)
        tempVal = execSQL.ExecuteScalar()
    End Using
End Sub
```

This generates my dynamic SQL string based on info in the table, and passes it to tempVal with the following result (2 selects and cross join):

Now yes, that SQL looks quite funky, and I apologise for the format so I will also paste the in-line sql here:

```sql
with tmp1(MyFieldName) as (select distinct t2.ORCHARDDETAILID from PESTMONITOR t2), tmp2(MyPivotSource) as (select 'iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = ' ||MyFieldName|| ', t2.QUANTITY, 0) as ' || MyFieldName || ' ' from tmp1) select 'select t2.MONITORDATE, '||list(distinct MyPivotSource)||' from PESTMONITOR t2 order by 1' from PESTMONITOR cross join tmp2
```

But I need to do it this way in order run the following:

```
Private Sub GridView()
    Try

        getPestList()

        Dim sql = tempVal

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New FbDataAdapter(sql, con)

        da.Fill(dt)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim pivotedTable As DataTable = PivotTable(dt)
            gvPCL.DataSource = pivotedTable
            gvPCL.DataBind()

        End If
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        Dim msg As String = "Fetch Error:"
        msg += ex.Message
        Throw New Exception(msg)

    End Try
End Sub
```

This populates my GridView with variable passed into FbDataAdapter

Expected results should be:

initial Sql result:

```
select t2.MONITORDATE, iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = 819, t2.QUANTITY, 0) as 819 ,iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = 836, t2.QUANTITY, 0) as 836 ,iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = 837, t2.QUANTITY, 0) as 837  from PESTMONITOR t2 order by 1
```

2nd sql result, as well as the GridView (after databind) should display this table:

```
            819         836         837                 
01.01.2019  0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
02.01.2019  0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
03.01.2019  0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
04.01.2019  0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
05.01.2019  0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
06.01.2019  0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
07.01.2019  0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
14.01.2019  0.000000    4.000000    0.000000
13.06.2019  2.000000    0.000000    0.000000
13.06.2019  3.000000    0.000000    0.000000
14.06.2019  1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

There are also one or two other things going on but they won't affect anything going on with this current issue. The main point is to display the counts of all the traps on the block numbers for all the dates. (could be 1 or could also be 1001)

the error I receive when da.Fill(dt) gets executed is the following:

```
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 73
819
```

so this is where the erorrs column name gets set

```
… select t2.MONITORDATE, iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = 819, t2.QUANTITY, 0) as 819 …
```

Why can my column name not be a number? I had to manually insert double quotes around the columns. to show the result grid above.

I have tried messing with `"`, `'` as well as a combination of these to try and escape it since I am setting this as a variable tempVal="SQL HERE" and have the statement totally break if I add any.

I am considering using a block function and am currently testing out ways to incorporate the selects in exec block stmt and/or s-proc to get round the `""` problem in the IDE

Edit: Thanks to Mark for pointing out the identifier limitation I was seemingly unaware of. I have been able to correct the error, without any manual intervention, by appending a single char before the column gets aliased with the row value as follows : ``` ' || [a-z/A-Z] || myValue || ' '. I might be able to strip this out with a substr or something like that in the code, but if not its not the end of the world I can make do. I have accepted his answer as correct in light of this.

Edit 2: The question is technically answered, but here is a Screenshot of what I meant to help clarify as a user suggested in the comments under Marks answer.[IDE View of the issue after adding quotes to specify value as a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umjqm.png).

As you can see, that's the reason I was struggling with it a bit. And why I thought building it separately line by line instead of a plain SQL statement would have been a better approach. I'm coming from a C#/MySQL background and I'm basically learning as I run into trouble and need to fix it, its far from where I would want it to be but its getting there.

For what its worth guys, thanks for taking the time to read through it and try to figure out what was what.

Final Edit/Note: Its now fully working, 100% as expected. Error was due to not fully understanding Column identifier constraints / variable set to column names in the SQL need to be defined as a String, using double double-quotes as such on this occasion `""' … '""`

Comment: A name (i.e., column alias) by default must be a string. So `select t2.MONITORDATE, iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = 819, t2.QUANTITY, 0) as '819' ,iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = 836, t2.QUANTITY, 0) as '836' ,iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = 837, t2.QUANTITY, 0) as '837'  from PESTMONITOR t2 order by 1` should work

Comment: What is your real question? Is it _"Why can my column name not be a number?"_? or is it something else? Also, are you using a dialect 1 or dialect 3 database. What errors are you getting if _"have the statement totally break if I add any."_?

Comment: @topshot Hi there, the issue is I cant input those single quotes manually. As I mentioned earlier its constructed by the initial query that builds all the columns in the select from the distinct value in each row. If I put in the extra quotes in this first SQL string in my Visual Studio, then there in an error upon the SQL being executed at the line ```tempVal = execSQL.ExecuteScalar()``` this doesn't run after the alteration because the format is not correct anymore. Apologies for not specifying this

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Good day Mark. Thank you for your insight, upon further investigation, you are 100% correct. I have been able to work around the issue by appending a single char before the variable by adding ``` ' || 'B' ``` to the front of it. I shall update the post and mark yours as answer. If that error was a bit better worded I think I would have figured it out eventually. I am still fairly new to fb as you can probably see by now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column or alias cannot start with a digit as it must comply with the rules documented in [Identifiers](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-structure-identifiers) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference. A regular identifier must start with an ASCII a-z or A-Z, so it cannot start with a digit.

If you want to use digits, then you must a quoted identifier, and quote the alias by enclosing it in double quotes.

You need to use `""` to escape the double quote, or in specifically your code `" (select 'iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = ' || Field || ', t2.QUANTITY, 0) as ""' || MyField || '"" ' from tmp1) " +`. That is two double quotes and a single quote (`""'`) before `|| MyField ||` and a single quote and two double quotes (`'""`) after.

Comment: Hi there. So the only issue I was having with using double quotes is that it breaks the statement in the IDE, what I mean by this, is that if I add double quotes at that location the rest of the query, like, "inverts" if I can call it that. Basically the "string" part of the initial concatenation (1st query is basically like a group_concat frm mysql), now becomes unquoted, and its just a nightmare. I suppose I could also have just split it up into like 5 or 6 parts then just added it to tempVal += itself. Anyway, I got it working now, also upvoted but it doesn't show, my reps too low.

Comment: @LukeBuddell show the screenshot of your IDE doing it. What you tell here sounds so strange that guesswork at our side might be futile. Also check your IDE is connecting to Firebird with SQL Dialect 3 not 1

Comment: Also notice `ASCII_CHAR()` function https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html

Comment: @Arioch'The  Afternoon, I have added another Edit at the bottom with a screenshot link, I cant embed anything or vote because of my rep. Thanks for the link as well I shall check it out shortly. Have a great day further

Comment: @LukeBuddell It sounds to me like you are unaware how to escape a double quote in a VB.net string. If I'm not mistaken (I don't use VB.net), you should use double double quotes in a string (so `""`). A single double quote will simply end your current string.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  ...or he just missed an operation between adjacent terms in expression ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The No, check the screenshot linked from the question. The `'` in `'  || MyField || ....` is outside the string, which causes it to be interpreted as a comment. This happens because the `"` just before it ends the VB.net string instead of rendering a double quote inside the string.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well spotted. Then perhaps he has to double the inner quote mark a la Pascal/Delphi. PDP-16 assembler had an interesting liberal convention there, ANY first char of the string constant was used as delimiter, so it could be anything, usually string started and ended with a slash. Here though, if language-level escaping would be not available, one can use Basic's standard `CHR$()` function or Firebird's `ascii_char()` one to insert the quote mark indirectly

Comment: To be honest I thought it was just ```" "``` , ```' '``` or ```" ' "```. I have tried to accomplish this in that specific example but I don't think its possible, since the value needs to be quoted anyway because its a variable, then its inside another quoted string in the SQL, inside the tempValue String. But there are also different layers of the query that don't get run the first time at all, and gets passed as a string. I did something very similar in MySQL which is what I structured it around but that was in Workbench, and using prepared stmt / tmp table which is so much easier

Comment: @LukeBuddell It is possible, and you need to use `""`, or in specifically your code `" (select 'iif(t2.ORCHARDDETAILID = ' || Field || ', t2.QUANTITY, 0) as ""' || MyField || '"" ' from tmp1) "` (that is two double quotes, and a single quote **before** `|| MyField ||`  and a single quote and two double quotes **after**.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, using to provide a "code".

About the IDE screenshot - now hover that red wave underline with mouse cursor and screenshot the information tooltip about the error - what exactly does it say? :-)

I suggest you to use different style when you creating lists with unknown in advance number of elements, in this case - a mega-string that consists of not yet known in advance number of shorter strings. Like this:

```
X = "aaaaa"
  + "bbbbb"
  + "ccccc"
  + "ddddd"
;
```

Instead of traditional and "bookish"

```
X = "aaaaaaaaaa" +
  "bbbbb" +
  "ccccccccccccc" + "ddddd";
```

Notice how plus here prepends the next item, not hides somewhere after it.

Also notice how all plus signs are on the same column - easy to spot them and to check them all there (or not).

Surely this goes against "typographics" we got used to by reading fiction books and newspapers, it looks very weird, etc. But give it a try.

In you specific case - you seem, after many of your edits after edits, to just loose one of those plus signs, and that is why IDE complains, you just introduced a syntax error of two strings following with nothing between them.

Comment: Although moving the `+` to the start of the next line may fix the red line, it doesn't fix the actual problem.

Comment: I am aware of the syntax error, I only pasted that there as an example to try to show what I meant with the quotes. It still will not run due to the nested sql string being built changes (reason for all the ```'``` everywhere, its literally a blob concatenation that gets executed againshortly afterwards) if you paste that inline SQL stmt into your IDE its a lot easier too see with the colour differences. But that said if I do manage to get it sorted out I will make an edit with how I got there. Also, if im not mistaken you cant use your + " " method in VB. It will also return a Syntax error